# I keep getting can't find '__main__' module in ...I am trying to run a code in sublime text, but this keeps coming up

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I have seen this question before , but the solutions given did not help. I saved it with.py extension before running it, as well as checked the auto and Python build system. Nothing works.

I am simply inserting an image, and changing it to gray. It is for an AI project. 
This is my code:

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np

 image = cv2.imread('test_image.jpg')
 lane_image = np.copy(image)
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(lane_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
 cv2.imshow('result', gray)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: What is this saved as and how are you running it?

Comment: As an additional comment to what @blueteeth mentioned, unless you're using a custom build system of some sort, using `waitkey()` is almost certainly going to hang your process indefinitely because standard Sublime build systems cannot be interactive. More information on the exact error you're seeing is needed in order to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @blueteeth. It's saved as lanes.py. It's being run under anaconda 3 command prompt.

Comment: @OdatNurd, What do you mean they cannot be interactive? I don't know what other info to provide. It's being run in Python. I am following a tutorial in making a AI car. They used Atom, which I tried, but I am getting the same issue as Sublime.

Comment: So in a terminal you are running `python3 lanes.py`?

Comment: Yes. lanes.py is the folder that the code is in and supposed to run. I am following a tutorial about making AI cars. I started with Atom, but that didn't help. So I switched to Sublime, and I am still having issues.

Comment: @MichaelPaxinos interactive means being able to interact with the program; that is, if it relies on you pressing a key, or entering some sort of input, then it's not going to work in Sublime unless you create a custom build system to do so.

Comment: Ok thank you. I used Atom first, but that didn't do anything. so I switched to Sublime, and then I get this main error thing.  I tried contacting the authors of the tutorial, I am still waiting. I cannot proceed unless its fixed.